# Nextjs image loades image but not showing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using react-responsive-carousel to make carousel, it was working fine but after 4 days its not showing images, when I debug, I see that images are there, but its not showing on screen. Console also is not giving any error.

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";

function Slider() { return (
<div className="relative">
  <div className="absolute w-full bottom-0 z-20" />
  <Carousel
    autoPlay
    infiniteLoop
    showStatus="{false}"
    showIndicators="{false}"
    showThumbs="{false}"
    interval="{5000}"
  >
    <div className="relative">
      <Image src={require("../public/Img/banner1.png")} width={1440} height={600} objectFit='cover'
      />
    </div>
    <div className="relative">
      <Image src={require("../public/Img/banner2.png")} width={1440} height={600} objectFit='cover'
      />
    </div>
    <div className="relative">
      <Image src={require("../public/Img/banner3.png")} width={1440} height={600} objectFit='cover'
      />
    </div>
    <div className="relative">
      <Image src={require("../public/Img/banner4.png")} width={1440} height={600} objectFit='cover'
      />
    </div>
    <div className="relative">
      <Image src={require("../public/Img/banner5.png")} width={1440} height={600} objectFit='cover'
      />
    </div>
    <div className="relative">
      <Image src={require("../public/Img/banner6.png")} width={1440} height={600} objectFit='cover'
      />
    </div>
  </Carousel>
</div>
); }

export default Slider;
```

Edits:
When I replaced next Image with img, its showing same error.

Comment: share a working link here....

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you reproduce the issue on different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the path from `../public/Img/banner6.png` to `/Img/banner6.png`.

Comment: Or try to <Image src={"/Img/banner4.png")} width={1440} height={600} objectFit='cover'>

Comment: its loading image correctly, but not displaying